# Is there a way to redirect stderror to stdout for the duration of a script in Windows?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, build-automation

As a long time UNIX shell scripter / release engineer coming into the Windows environment full time with my latest job, there are some things I inevitably miss.

One of them is my trusty old 'exec 2>&1' which in the Bourne shell permently knots together stderr and stdout for the duration of the script, so that logging will capture everything good and bad.

I realize you can append 2>foo.log to the end of every command line invocation, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Is there any equivalent in the Windows environment? We're using both .BAT file scripts and Perl scripts here (Mostly for build automation but also some other things) and I'd dearly love to know if this is possible at all.

Comment: You probably meant 2>>foo.log there.  That little gaffe caused a fair amount of hair loss one night, some years ago....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the .BAT that does the real work inside a .BAT that redirects the streams for logging.

Something like

```
rem log.bat
cmd /c work.bat 1>>logfile.log 2>&1
```

```
rem work.bat
make all
perl cleanups.pl
```

might do the trick. You might be able to use CALL instead of directly invoking a second CMD.EXE, I haven't checked. If that does work, then the solution can be self contained: just call yourself with an extra argument to indicate the logging is in effect and with the streams redirected.

Answer (score 5):

In Perl you can do

```
open STDERR, '>&STDOUT' or die "Can't dup STDOUT";
```

to redirect the STDERR output of the script to STDOUT. See the [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) documentation for more info. I wouldn't expect this to effect the output of system calls, i.e. `system` or backticks.

Comment: It does affect the output of system calls and backticks.  Those subprocesses get whatever STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR handles are open in Perl at the time they are called.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply redirection to command blocks as well as single commands

```
(
echo 1
dir
echo 2
) >somefile.txt
```

Note that it is impossible to use labels and goto inside of command blocks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930) from MS. Sample taken from the said article:

> You can print the errors and standard output to a single file by using the "&1" command to redirect the output for STDERR to STDOUT and then sending the output from STDOUT to a file:

```
 dir file.xxx 1> output.msg 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think you read the question.  I know I can redirect stdout and stderr for each command invocation, what I want is to do said redirect for the duration of a script.

Comment: My point was: I don't see any problem using the above with a script. However, AFAIK, there is no special STDERR for batch files.

Answer (score 0):

The `2>&1` thing seems to be working for me for scripts:

```
testcmd.cmd > stdboth.txt 2>&1
```

What exactly are you doing and what are you expecting when you're doing it?

Comment: Thanks but as I said in the question, I'm looking for something that redirects stderr to stdout for the *entire script* - not just a single command invocation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'entire script' - in the above example stdout and stderr seem to be redirected for all the commands in the testcmd.cmd script (and any scripts it calls).  The commands within the script do not need to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
:log_me
@if "%~1" NEQ "*" ("%~nx0" * >> "%~n0.log" 2>&1)

:script
echo this is success
echo this is error>&2
```

And, if your batch script has command line parameters:

```
:log_me
@call :script %* >> "%~n0.log" 2>&1
exit /b

:script
echo this is success
echo this is error>&2
```